# Javascript: replace text inside <div>foo <span>text </span>bar</div> by <div>foo text bar</div>

Tags: javascript, html, string

Just as the title suggests, lets consider the following html snippet:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>foo <span>text </span>bar</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to transform it by removing the span tags, but keeping the text they contain in the same location, such as

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>foo text bar</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to do that in javascript. Because this task is (I suppose) uncommon (I am in fact trying to build a GUI for marking data for NLP) I could not really find a solution browsing SO or Google... And I am very new to javascript so I didn't really know where to start.

Aditional question:
If one know how to resolve the first question, maybe can quickly mention how to perform the same transformation on all document span, such as the following document:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>foo <span>text </span>bar</div>
    <div>foo1 <span>text1 </span>bar1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

becomes

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>foo text bar</div>
    <div>foo1 text1 bar1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thx

Comment: explanation on why this is being downvoted would be appreciated...

Comment: Is that snippet a `String` or are the elements already inside the DOM?

Comment: Note that there are *no actual spaces* in `<div>foo<span>text</span>bar</div>`. Are you sure that you want to **insert spaces**, even though there are **none** in the original? If not, then please be more exact with your input/output spec. Furthermore, I'm pretty sure that downvote(s) are for not including any code that you tried yourself ('no effort').

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Comment: document.querySelector('div').textContent = document.querySelector('div').textContent; should do the trick (there would be no spaces though)

Comment: @David, Gabriel Souto made the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `outerHTML` of `<span>` to its `innerHTML`

```js
var elms = document.querySelectorAll('div *');

elms.forEach(e => e.outerHTML = ` ${e.innerHTML} `)

//just to test the effect.
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(x => console.log(x.outerHTML))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>foo<span>text</span>bar</div>
<div>foo1<span>text1</span>bar1</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `replace`:

```js
let div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace("<span>", " ").replace("</span>", " ");
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">foo<span>text</span>bar</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("div").each(function(index,item){
        $(item).html($(item).html().replace(/<\/?span[^>]*>/g,""));
     })
    })
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("div").each(function(index,item){
    $(item).html($(item).html().replace(/<\/?span[^>]*>/g,""));
 })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>foo <span>text</span> bar</div>
<div>foo1 <span>text1</span> bar1</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be to change innerHtml to innerText (if you want to get rid of all inner tags):

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].innerHTML = divs[i].innerText;
}
```

```css
span {color:red;}
```

```html
<div>foo <span>text </span>bar</div>
<div>foo1 <span>text1 </span>bar1</div>
```